# what is meant by the things inside the square bracket infront of a variable in ASN.1 data object?

Tags: smartcard, tlv

> euiccSignature1 [APPLICATION 55] OCTET STRING, --EUICC_Sign1, tag 5F37

the above is what I have in an ASN.1 data object. I'm going to DER encode it. can somebody please tell me what I have to do with that "tag 5F37" and what is inside that square bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the BER tag encoding rules first, then DER is just a subset of it, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding). Work the bits together and you will get `0x5F37`. The square brackets are the encoding format for an Application, the its an application specific Octet String and has a certain meaning according to the application it is used in. For more infos on the notation look [here](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html)